# Localsolr wt=json and fl compatible?

Tags: lucene, solr, localsolr

We've got Localsolr (2.9.1 lucene-spatial library) running on Solr 1.4 with Tomcat 1.6.  Everything's looking good, except for a couple little issues.

If we specify fl=id (or fl= anything) and wt=json it seems that the fl parameter is ignored (thus we get a lot more detail in our results than we'd like).

If we specify fl=id and leave out wt=json (which defaults to returning xml results), we get the expected fields back.  We'd really prefer to use wt=json because the results are easier for us to deal with (also, the same issue also arises with wt=python and wt=ruby).

Ideas? Known issue? Workarounds?

Comment: This looks like a bug, I'm seeing the same behavior. Please report it to http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-773

Comment: Thanks for the verification :) I've submitted a bug report now.

Comment: Brian... If you manage to get a working version.. Can you let me know by posting a comment on here. I see from Solr-773 that you've posted the bug report. I'll also check on there from time to time :)

Comment: Hey, I submitted a patch to the person that maintains localsolr that "fixes" this, in a non-ideal way (at a higher level than is most efficient).  Localsolr looks like it's getting phased out though and Solr 1.5 will essentially include all this functionality.